# WooCommerce Custom Thankyou redirection based on Product ID

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, redirect, orders

How can I redirect WooCommerce customers to a specific thank you page based on the products they purchased? I have one product that requires a form to be filled out for further information, and I would like to place that form on a thank you page. The code I have so far is below, but that's just for a generic thank you page for all products.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wc_custom_redirect_after_purchase' ); 

function wc_custom_redirect_after_purchase() {
    global $wp;

    if ( is_checkout() && ! empty( $wp->query_vars['order-received'] ) ) {
        wp_redirect( 'http://www.yoururl.com/your-page/' );
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: you will need a meta property to save the id of the custom page you want to redirect to after the purchase

Comment: What does not work about your code? What are your requirements. As it stands, I'd consider this question as too broad.

Answer (score 4):

Below in that function you will have to set your targeted product IDs or product categories, to get a custom redirection for this items when they are in the order:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wc_custom_redirect_after_purchase' );
function wc_custom_redirect_after_purchase() {
    if ( ! is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-received' ) ) return;

    // Define the product IDs in this array
    $product_ids = array( 37, 25, 50 ); // or an empty array if not used
    // Define the product categories (can be IDs, slugs or names)
    $product_categories = array( 'clothing' ); // or an empty array if not used
    $redirection = false;

    global $wp;
    $order_id =  intval( str_replace( 'checkout/order-received/', '', $wp->request ) ); // Order ID
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id ); // Get an instance of the WC_Order Object

    // Iterating through order items and finding targeted products
    foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ){
        if( in_array( $item->get_product_id(), $product_ids ) || has_term( $product_categories, 'product_cat', $item->get_product_id() ) ) {
            $redirection = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    // Make the custom redirection when a targeted product has been found in the order
    if( $redirection ){
        wp_redirect( home_url( '/your-page/' ) );
        exit;
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Tested on WooCommerce 3 and works.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of a simple page redirect:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wc_custom_redirect_after_purchase');

function bbloomer_redirectcustom( $order_id ){
$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

$url = 'http://yoursite.com/custom-url';

if ( $order->status != 'failed' ) {
    wp_redirect($url);
    exit;
  }
}
```